# Interviewed yesterday, they emailed me a benefits brochure shortly after. Is this a good sign, or common for companies to do?

Tags: hiring-process, benefits

Interviewed yesterday for a company, about 3 hours afterwards, the HR person I've been in contact with sent me their benefits brochure. Its just like a 2-page information sheet, not like a full in-depth employee information packet or anything.

I didn't ask about benefits at all in the interview and they sent it to me before I even had the chance to send them a thank-you email. So, is this a good sign that the interview went well and they liked me or is this something that companies usually do? I was under the impression that benefits aren't really discussed until an offer is made, but not sure. I'm excited but don't want to get my hopes up. Thanks!

Comment: Don't read to much into this. They are just telling you more about their benefits.

Comment: Probably either a standard (i.e. everyone gests this, whatever happens), or a mistake. I agree with @JustanotherJavaprogrammer : don't read much into that.

Answer (score 16):

There is no way to tell, it could be their usual policy, or a mistake, or they intend to offer you the job.

But

It's definitely not a bad sign.

Comment: Pretty much. It can be neutral or good, but there's not really a way for it to be a bad sign.

Answer (score 4):

Companies don't like to give false hope, or waste time.

It is a good sign

Answer (score 2):

It is a good sign, but the only sure thing of progress in the recruitment process is an offer letter / contract

Answer (score 0):

It is very unusual for a hiring manager or recruiter to send any benefits related information to a prospect without prompting. Most likely, it was a mistake or an automated process, although it could be a sign that they are interested but have not yet formed a formal offer. I would lean towards it being "insignificant" rather than being a positive sign of any intent.